# Is oauth2 appropriate for closed API access via mobile client?

Tags: iphone, ipad, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm seen OAuth2 bandied as the next authentication scheme.  The context has been allowing third party clients to authenticate without giving up username/password.

What about the case where I have an API that is not intended for third party access--the only users will be end users via a mobile client that I provide?  Would OAuth2 still be appropriate in this case or could I get by using one of the more popular existing schemes, eg HTTP AUTH?

Comment: How are you making sure that the call is only open to your mobile client? Is it not possible for someone to bypass your mobile client and make a call.

Comment: The security should be no tighter than the user authenticated to the server via web browser.  I wouldn't authenticate the client software, just the access to the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this sort of thing if you want, it's generally referred to as "two legged Oauth".  Oauth is a pretty complicated protocol.  It needs to be, since it's doing something that's pretty complicated.

Anyhow, we use a two legged Oauth for a few things at work and it greatly over complicates things.  The way we're using it, it just ends up a more complicated version of HTTP's Basic Auth, but without any real benefits.  There are some valid use cases for two legged oauth, but I don't think replacing Basic Auth should be one of them. http://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/2leggedoauth/2opensocialrestapi is a good example of why you might want to use a two legged Oauth, there are a few more scattered around the web.

I'd recommend staying away from it unless you can think of a good, concrete reason to use it.  Don't use it just because it's trendy.

Comment: I'll KISS to start.  HTTP AUTH+HTTPS.  I'll upgrade when I need to.

Comment: Good plan.  I had to resort to reading the spec just to figure out enough to get some simple client/server auth running.  But maybe I'm just confused...

Comment: I always read the spec.  It's the only authoritative source, and for complex authentication stuff, you really want the authority on the subject — it's way too easy for some tutorial or something to get an important detail wrong.